# For loop in unix shell scripting

Tags: unix, for-loop

I want to run a curl command, in which one parameter has to run through FOR loop.
Say

```
curl -i -vs -X POST -H "$SESSION_TOKEN"  "http://$PLATFORM/videos/VIDEO_ID/play"
```

Here, the VIDEO_ID i want run it from 7500 to 8500 video id's. How can i do it?

Comment: Its in the shell script i am executing. A quick help is really helpful

Comment: write a loop... what's the problem?

Comment: Yup... sounds like you want a `for` loop. You might want to read through `man bash` if that's your shell (or `man ksh` or `man sh` or, if you really must and have no other alternatives, `man csh`).

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
for i in {7500..8500}; do
    curl -i -vs -X POST -H "$SESSION_TOKEN" "http://$PLATFORM/videos/$i/play"
done
```

Comment: Thanks.. its a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "unix shell" you mean something like Bash, you can use an "arithmetic for loop":

```
for (( video_id = 7500 ; video_id <= 8500 ; ++video_id )) ; do
    curl -i -vs -X POST -H "$SESSION_TOKEN" \
        "http://$PLATFORM/videos/$video_id/play"
done
```

Comment: Beats you by 8 seconds ;)